# Is it possible to group sql join results by a common column? Please see the description

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate

I'm super rusty with databases and haven't got the chance to work too much with them in the past 6-8 years, so there are some things that are uncertain for me.

Let's assume I have a simple bi-directional one-to-many situation:

```
Parent
------
id
```

and

```
Child
-----
id
age
parent_id
```

and I want to perform a query which will return all the parents together with the matching children that follow some rules.

For example let's assume we have

```
Parent: [Child (age 5), Child (age 8), Child (age 10)]
Parent: [Child (age 8), Child (age 15)]
Parent: [Child (age 20)]
```

and I want to obtain the parents together with their children filtered for example by age (less than 10).

This situations screams a join with a where statement - something like:

```sql
SELECT Parent.id, Child.id, Child.age
    FROM Parent LEFT JOIN Child ON Parent.id = Child.parent_id 
    WHERE Child.age < 10;
```

And this will work fine and return 3 entries - two rows for parent1 with the children that match the rule and one for parent two and its children.

However, my question is - can I group it somehow based on Parent Id?
Can I use `LIMIT` for limiting the number of Parents? (For example in this case limit 2 will return all results - because there are two parents that match the criteria)

Background context - I'm trying to implement this with Java, Hibernate and a Postgres db. I'm using `OneToMany`/`ManyToOne` relationships and `CriteriaQuery` in order to interogate the DB.

Comment: use recursive CTE and there you can limit what ever you like :D even the number of iteratiions

Comment: Do you need the Child's ID and Child Age in your select statement?  You could just run a distinct on the Parent ID and it would only display the Parent ID's that meet that condition regardless of children.  To me it sounds like you just want the distinct Parent ID's that meet the conditions.

Comment: @Vlookup - In my real world scenario both the parent and the child have more columns that are of interest. Distinct wouldn't help since I would lose the information I want to be extracted from the child columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you want to limit two parents, but this could mean more than two rows because a parent can have more than one child under the age of 10?  If so, the `count` analytic function can start numbering parents, and you can set the limit by taking the resulting count <= 2:

```
with qualifying_parents as (
  select
    c.id, c.age, c.parent_id,
    count (parent_id) over (partition by parent_id) as cnt
  from
    child c
    join parent p on c.parent_id = p.id
  where
    c.age < 10
)
select id as child_id, age, parent_id
from qualifying_parents
where cnt <= 2
```

This would give you three rows from your example but only two distinct parent ids.

Also, in this example, the `parent` table is unnecessary, but I assume it has more attributes than just ID that you intend to use in your query.

Alternatively, you can leverage Postgres` most excellent array functionality and then invoke a simple limit clause at the end of your query:

```
select
  parent_id, array_agg(age) as children_ages
from child c
where age < 10
group by parent_id
limit 2
```

(I omitted parent there, but you can put it back obviously).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yup this suffices my needs and covers my flows. Also, you assumed right about the join and other fields. Thank you again for the solution - unfortunately I was not aware of the `array_agg` function of Postgres.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Arrays in Postgres are amazing.  They solve so many things, and I never run out of ways to use them.  I think it's one of the biggest advantages of Pg over other RDBMS systems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a GROUP BY clause on a SQL join result the same as on a select from a single table. However, as in all uses of GROUP BY, every column in the output that is not also in the group clause needs to be the result of some [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html). For example, you could write

```sql
SELECT Parent.id, min(child_age) 
    FROM Parent LEFT JOIN Child ON Parent.id = Child.parent_id 
    WHERE Child.age < 10
    GROUP BY Parent.id; -- Add LIMIT 2 here if you want
```

To get each parent with a young child and the age of their youngest child.

If all you want is an arbitrary value from the child columns, you can instead use `DISTINCT ON(Parent.Id)`. For example,

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Parent.id) parent.id, child.id as child_id, child.age as child_age
    FROM Parent LEFT JOIN Child ON Parent.id = Child.parent_id 
    Limit 2;
```

Will give you a single row per parent id with some child id and child age for that parent.

If you don't actually need the child columns to be returned, just used in the join, then just don't include them in the select.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately both your solutions are missing important column or entry data from the children table which I want to retrieve.